# Why $\{\emptyset\} \not \subset\{\{\emptyset\}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In my text book it is written that:

> **`{ } ⊆ { }; { } ⊆ {0/}; { } ⊆ { {0/} }; { } ⊆ C`**; and **`{0/} ⊆ C; {
>   {0/} } ⊆ C`**; but **`{0/}`** is not a subset of **`{ {0/} }`** since the only
>   element of **`{0/}`** is **`0/`** and the only element of **`{ {0/} }`** is
>   **`{0/}`**, so the element of **`{0/}`** is not an element of **`{ {0/} }`**.

A set with no elements is an empty set, denoted by **`{0/}`**.

There are three parts to my question.

Firstly, what is the distinction between **`{0/}`** and **`{ }`**? Why is the latter not an empty set like the former?

Secondly, is **`{ {0/} }`** an element and at the same time a set?

And finally, howcome is **`{0/}`** is not a subset of **`{ {0/} }`**? How can an empty set not be a subset of an empty set?

This is my first question on math.stackexchange: I have no formal Mathematics background so please don't presume too much as much as I want to learn...

Thank you, internet!

**UPDATE:** Let C = **`{ 0/, {0/} }`**

Comment: I think that this was covered at least four times before on the site.

Comment: Close enough duplicates: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135218/set-theory-subset-of-set/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638560/why-can-a-1-element-set-be-a-member-of-another-set-but-not-a-subset-of-it (and there are exact duplicates too)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, a link would greatly be appreciated then!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `{ }`?

Comment: { } can be taken to mean a set, all of whose elements have been removed.

Comment: So what's the difference between that and $\emptyset$?

Comment: Note, by the way, that $\{\varnothing\}$ is not empty. It has an element.

Comment: @GPerez, the author of the textbook I am reading gives the subset {} as a subset of any set.

Comment: I fixed up the latex for title, can you fix up the rest please?