# Is the set inside a set subset of the bigger set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I just started set theory (ncert maths 11th grade) and it had a question:

> Let $A = \{1 , 2 , \{3,4\} , 5 , 6\}$
>
> Is $\{3,4\}$ a subset of A?

The book said no.
I think the answer should be yes, since $A$ contains a set which contains the elements $3,4$ hence $A$ contains $3,4$ and by the definition of subset $\{3,4\}$ should be a subset of $A$.

Comment: While the set in question is different, the principle is the same.

Comment: I was just about to post this as an answer before the question was closed, but I'll include it anyway since using OP's example may help understanding: 

The book is correct: $A$ doesn't contain $3$, nor does it contain $4$ even though it does contain a set containing $3$ and $4$. It's important to distinguish between these notions! It is the case that $\{1,2\}$ is a subset of $A$, since all the elements of $\{1,2\}$ are also elements of $A$, and it is the case that $\{3,4\}$ is itself an element of $A$, but $\{3,4\}$ is not a subset of $A$.

Comment: @B.Mehta: As a principle, always assume that *all* the basic questions are duplicates. At least until you put some effort into finding a suitable duplicate, or the lack thereof.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I'd expected this to be a duplicate but I couldn't find a duplicate in the related list which addressed this concern, nor on the [list of common questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions) so I started writing an answer anyway.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In fact it may be worth adding the duplicate target to that list, it does seem like a very common question.

Comment: @B.Mehta: If you have some suggestions, I'd be happy to add them.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm sure you'll know better than I, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638560/why-can-a-1-element-set-be-a-member-of-another-set-but-not-a-subset-of-it) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135218/set-theory-subset-of-set/) probably ought to be on that list, under the same bullet point.

Comment: I am sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: "since A contains a set which contains the elements 3,4 hence A contains 3,4" That is a fundamental misconception.  A does *not* contain 3 or 4, it contains a *set* that contains 3 and 4.  A set does not contain the stuff inside it's elements.  Think of it like a phone book.  A phonebook contains people.  My library contains a phone book.  But my library does not contain people.  (That would be slavery and that is morally wrong.)

Comment: "I am sorry for inconvenience"  You should not be sorry for asking a legitimate question.  And this is a *very* legitimate question.  Search this site for answers can be difficult so no one can blame you asking a question that has already been answered.

Comment: Someone might argue that a phonebook does not contain people but *references* to people.  Okay, but what about a cafeteria that sells bag lunches containing bananas but does not sell bananas?  Or... I *hate* this analogy, but eveyone else finds it useful... think of sets as "bags" holding things.  If you have a bag with a 1, a 2 and another bag inside it that has a 3 and a 4, the outer bag doesn't actually have the stuff in the inner bag as its contents.  It just has the bag itself.

Comment: @fleablood This is where I think I am wrong: If B is a subset of A, then every element in B is an element in A. But in here, 3 and 4 are not elements of A, but they are elements of an element in A. So basically when we say a /epsilon A, then we mean that a is an element of A, a does not belong to A. About your phonebook example, phonebook contains people's number not people either, hence the library contains people's number, which makes sense, to me.

Comment: "a does not belong to A".  The meaning of "belong to" is not clear.  $a \in A$ means $a$ is an element of $A$.  $B\subset A$ means be is a set and that all the elements that are in $B$ are elements of $A$.  Member ship is not transitive.  If $a \in B$ and $B \in A$ that does *not* mean $a \in A$.  I am member The AlphaFinger Society.  And the AlphaFinger Society *is* a collection of people.  And the AlphaFinger Society is a member The Associated Coalition of Societies which *is* a collection of societies. But *i*'m not a member of the ACS which has societies, not people, as members.

Comment: @fleablood, ohk so in set theory, belongs to means it is an element of the set and not like, it is *inside* it (like a ball in box)

Comment: That's strange way of looking at it but if it works for you...  I personally do think of elements as being inside the set but not nested layers deep inside the set.  I'd say $A=\{a,b,\{c,d\}\}$ has three things *inside* it; the $a$, $b$ and $\{c,d\}$.  the stuff that are nested inside $\{c,d\}$ are not directly inside $A$ but nested too deep.  But "inside" is just a ... words.  The elements of $A$ are $a$, $b$ and $\{c,d\}$.  That's it.  The elements *within* elements are not elements.  A set is a list (where order doesn't matter) and $c$ and $d$ are simply *not* on the list.

Comment: ... and corporations are NOT people!